Is it possible to scale along arbitrary axes?
Using Blender 3.4 (for feature requirement reasons), and I would like to scale these vertices in edit mode, but I'd like to scale it along an arbitrary axis, as shown in this image (orange line being the desired axis):

These vertices are not near the object origin point, and the object's local axes are the same as the global axes, so the vertices can't be stretched on local axes.
I am aware that I can select the vertices, rotate them until the desired scale axis is lined up with a global axis, and then return them, but this process makes it difficult to size them based on a reference (I'd have to rotate, scale, unrotate, check, rotate, adjust, unrotate, check again, repeat ad nauseam), so it's not ideal. Is there a more intuitive solution?
(Googling also produced something about creating axes, but the post was from 2010 and I'm unable to find the mentioned feature in my version.)

Select the edge you want to align your scale with, open the Transform Orientations panel, click on the "+" button, you'll get a new orientation, scale along the axis you want (for me it will be Y):

